# How to call ioctl with commands SIOCGIFFLAGS and SIOCSIFFLAGS atomically

Tags: linux, atomic, system-calls

Is there a way to call ioctl (the question is also valid for all sys calls) with commands `SIOCGIFFLAGS` and `SIOCSIFFLAGS` in an atomic manner? For example if i would add the `IFF_PROMISC` flag to an interface:

```
...
struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0");

if (ioctl(sk, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0)
...

ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
if (ioctl(sk, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0)
...
```

how can i ensure that these two calls are made atomically?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't - there is no way to guarantee that another process hasn't changed the flags in between those calls.

Comment: I imagined this :( Thank Tom.